# Cannot create a confidential token account using Token2022

Tags: spl-token, token, token-extensions

I am trying to follow the quickstart guide [here](https://spl.solana.com/confidential-token/quickstart), and when I get to the third command, trying to configure a confidential transfer account on Solana testnet, and I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Client(Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to load a program that does not exist", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(ProgramAccountNotFound), logs: Some([]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None }) }) })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the ZK Token Proof program is not yet enabled.

It's undergoing an audit and once that's done it can be enabled.

This is also mentioned in [the documentation](https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/status):

> All clusters have the latest program deployed **without confidential transfer functionality**.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that page.